# Use Emacs for Sql template

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to frequently call a bunch of sql queries. Here is the simplest example of them:

```
SELECT A.<col_a>
FROM <TABLE_A> A 
INNER JOIN <TABLE_B> B
ON A.<col_a> = B.<col_b>
```

What's a convenient way to use emacs to replace the macros to produce a valid sql query?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want Emacs to do.  If you want to fill in the bracked text by hand, I'd use [yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet).  You can define macros with holes and tab between them.

Answer (score 0):

For template, you might want read this [Emacs: How to Define Templates in YASnippet](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/yasnippet_templates_howto.html)

If you also want some completion, check out [Emacs EDBI](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-edbi/commits/master)